# ramda.js - how to apply a fn to subset of a collection

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm looking for an elegant way to apply a function (`assoc` for example) to a subset of a collection, but return the full collection.  A similar idea was proposed as [lensWhere](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2257).

One way of doing this in JS would be:

```
const applyToSubset = fn => predicate => col =>
    col.filter(item => !predicate(item))
    .concat(
        col.filter(item => predicate(item))
        .map(fn)
    )
```

Of course, this approach reorders the collection, which is not ideal.

Is there a more standard way to do this with ramda.js or functional idioms?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you give us more specific information on the output you want?  IE: input and output types.

Comment: `const applyToSubset = fn => predicate => col =>
    col.map(item => predicate(item)?fn(item):item);`

Comment: @eguneys that definitely works - is there an existing idiom for this?  like lensWhere + over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably write it like this with Ramda:

```js
const applyToSubset = (fn) => (pred) => map (when (pred, fn))

console .log (
  applyToSubset (triple) (isOdd) ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])
)  //~> [8, 6, 21, 15, 9, 0, 27]

console .log (
  applyToSubset (triple) (isOdd) ({a: 8, b: 6, c: 7, d: 5, e: 3, f: 0, g: 9})
)  //~> {a: 8, b: 6, c: 21, d: 15, e: 9, f: 0, g: 27}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
  const {map, when, multiply} = R
  const isOdd = n => n % 2 == 1;
  const triple = multiply(3)
</script>
```

While there might be some point-free way of doing this, it's already quite readable.

Comment: your implementation keeps the order of the original list, while the OP seems to ask for a kind of sorting where matches are put at the end of the list

Comment: @Hitmands: In fact that's intentional.  From the OP, "Of course, this approach reorders the collection, which is not ideal."

Comment: @ScottSauyet really nice solution

Comment: picking this for it's elegance

Comment: Is there a reason for the order of your parameters (i.e. `fn` then `pred`)? Otherwise the point-free version could be `curryN(2, compose(map, when))`

Comment: @customcommander: I was just matching the version in the question.

Comment: @customcommander nice suggestion - I feel like it actually could make sense to reverse those.  predicate before operation

Comment: It's a hard question to decide which parameter order is more natural here.  Still, even in reversing them, I believe that the equivalent of the above reads better than the point-free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick recap, you want to `partition` the original list and have non matching to the predicate on the left, and matching on the right `Tuple(non-matches, matches)`. Then apply `fn` to matches only. Finally flatten the list again.

```js
const applyToSubset = R.curry((fn, predicate, list) => R.pipe(
  R.partition(R.complement(predicate)),
  R.over(R.lensIndex(1), R.map(fn)),
  R.flatten
)(list));
    
    
const predicate = n => n >= 5;
const square = n => n * n;
const list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(
  'result',
  applyToSubset(square, predicate, list)
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

---

If you are not interested on the partition, but want to keep the original array order... then you can try this:

```js
const applyToSubset = R.converge(R.map, [
  (fn, filter) => R.when(filter, fn),
  R.nthArg(2),
]);
    
    
const predicate = n => n >= 5;
const square = n => n * n;
const list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(
  'result',
  applyToSubset(square, predicate, list)
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: your second solution is exactly what i was looking for.  perhaps i wasn't clear in my post, but was looking to preserve the original order.

Answer (score 0):

There's still a very simple approach using `Array#map`: just check each item and apply the whole function `f` to those elements which output `true` when applying each one to `predicate`.

```js
const applyToSubset = f => predicate => xs => 
    xs.map (x => predicate (x) ? f (x) : x)
    
const { assoc } = R
    
    
const input = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }]
const output = applyToSubset (assoc ('y') (1)) (({ x }) => x > 1) (input)

console.log (output)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```